# Uniform Continuity on an unbounded domain

Tags: real-analysis

The function $f(x) = sin(x)cos(x)$ is continuous on $(-\infty, \infty)$. Is it uniformly continuous?

-No, since the domain is not closed or bounded, the domain is not compact, thus the function is not uniformly continuous on  $(-\infty, \infty)$.

-I'm not over simplifying this correct?

Comment: What definition of uniform continuity do you use? By the way, $f(x)$ is indeed uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Well, I was just going off of the idea that a function that is continuous at each point of a compact domain is uniformly continuous. I thought that since it is unbounded on the domain, it is not uniformly continuous on the domain. Is there another definition of uniform continuity that I am forgetting about?

Comment: You are talking about the theorem saying "If a function $f$ is continuous on a compact domain $K$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$." That is NOT the definition of uniform continuity. You can look the definition up on Wikipedia if you've never heard of it before.

Comment: I can write a full answer to this question if you'd prefer so. Tell me if you want me to.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Oh okay, the definition of uniform continuity uses the delta-epsilon definition. For trig functions isn't this rather messy? I would enjoy seeing a full answer, but if that is too much work, just pointing me in the right direction for the proof would be great, thanks.

Comment: I decided to write a full answer. You should be able to understand it if you're familiar with $\epsilon-\delta$ proof. Hope that help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the definition of uniform continuity, $f$ is uniformly continuous on a domain $D$ if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $x,y\in D$ satisfy the relation $|x-y|<\delta$.

Knowing this, we proceed to find such a $\delta$ for any given $\epsilon$. From the Mean Value Theorem, we know that if $f$ is continuously differentiable, then for any $x\ne y$, there exists $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
f(y)-f(x)=f'(\xi)(y-x)
$$
which implies that
$$
|f(y)-f(x)|=|f'(\xi)||y-x|.
$$
Now, we should be almost finished if we can find a bound for $|f'(\xi)|$, but recall that 
$$
|f'(x)|=|\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)|\le|\cos^2(x)|+|\sin^2(x)|\le1+1=2\ ,
$$
combining the 2 previous inequalities, we have
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|\le 2|x-y|.
$$
Choose $\delta=\frac \epsilon2$ and we are done.

Comment: This is a special case of a theorem "If $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, then $f$ is uniformly continuous."

Comment: great, this is exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: @RedShift Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 5):

You're not correct.  Let $f\colon X\to\mathbb R$ be continuous.   Then it is true that

> \begin{align}
> X\textrm{ is compact  }&\Longrightarrow f\textrm{ is uniformly continuous}
> \end{align}

However, the converse is not true:

> \begin{align}
> f\textrm{ is uniformly continuous  } &\mathrel{\rlap{\hskip .5em/}}\Longrightarrow X\textrm{ is compact}
> \end{align}

In your case, you have a domain $X$ that is not compact, but the function $f$ is nevertheless uniformly continuous - for example, because it is differentiable and its derivative is bounded.

Answer (score 4):

Cleary a constant function on $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$ So uniform continuity does not imply the domain is compact.

The answer to your specific problem follows from a general result: Every continuous periodic function on $\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$ How could this not be true? If $|y-x|< p,$ where $p$ is the period, then then there exists an integer $n\in \mathbb Z$ such that $x-np,y-np \in [0,2p].$ Now $f$ is continuous on $[0,2p],$ hence is uniformly continuous there. The result follows.

Comment: Indeed, any periodic function on $\mathbb R$ factors as $\mathbb R\xrightarrow{\pi}S^1\xrightarrow{f}\mathbb R$, where $\pi$ is an appropriate projection map.  $\pi$ is uniformly continuous by the definition of the quotient metric and $f$ is uniformly continuous since $S^1$ is compact.  Then their composition must be uniformly continuous.